# LinkedIn API JavaScript - How to collect data in XML format

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

This is probably going to seem like a silly question as there are so many tutorials on the web detailing how to do stuff like this, but I'm just not getting anywhere with it!

I have a login button up and working on my website, but once a user has given their permission for me to use their data and signed in, how do I save their profile information in XML to, say, a database, or have it emailed to me?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!